# scp from inside a GCP VM to another server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to transfer the file `samtools.tar.bz2`  from inside a VM instance to another server outside GCP called `username@server.uni.no:` However, I get the following error:

```
gcloud beta compute scp --project "absolute-bison-xxxx" --zone "europe-west4-a" samtools.tar.bz2 username@server.uni.no:/home/local/user
```

error

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.scp) Could not fetch resource:  - Invalid value 'server.uni.no'. Values must match the following regular expression: '[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?|[1-9][0-9]{0,19}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/scp):

> (BETA) gcloud beta compute scp securely copies files between a virtual machine instance and your local machine using the scp command.
> (...)
> When the destination of your transfer is local, all source files must be from the same virtual machine.
> When the destination of your transfer is remote instead, all sources must be local.

It won't work with two remote machines, even if they are both in GCP.

A crude workaround is to download the file to your local machine:
`gcloud beta compute scp --project "absolute-bison-xxxx" --zone "europe-west4-a" USERNAME@INSTANCE_NAME:~/samtools.tar.bz2 samtools.tar.bz2`
and then upload it to the external server:
`scp samtools.tar.bz username@server.uni.no:/home/local/user`